# Cannot insert into mysql from node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have found some replies but I don't understand how to get the solution to my problem.

db.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'dbuser',
    database: 'voley_db'
});

module.exports = connection;
```

registroRoute.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('../db');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    db.query('SELECT * FROM usuarios', function (err, users) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.render(
                'registro', {
                users: users
            });
        }
    });
});

router.post('/crearCuenta', function (req, res) {
    var user = {
        nombre: req.body.nombre,
        apelldo: req.body.apellido,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    };

    db.query("INSERT INTO usuarios SET ?", user, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.send(result);
        }
    });
}); 

module.exports = router;
```

my tabale "usuarios" is:

- id
- nombre
- apellido
- email
- password

When I try to create the user, I get:

> {"code":"ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR","errno":1054,"sqlState":"42S22","index":0}

I can't understand why is happening this.

Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your column names is wrong, specifically your object has a key name of "apelldo" but you mentioned that your schema uses "apell***i***do."

Comment: I can't believe it. Sorry for wasting your time